# "Copying logs to installed system" is the installation already finished?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, vmware

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my ESXi 6.5 as VM, I am using the ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso, but it gets stuck at the last procedure, it shows "copying logs to installed system" and the bar at bottom shows 12/13, but it is already on this screen for 1-2 hours and there's no further progress. There is a *Reboot* button I can press and go forward, but I'd like to know if the installation is already finished?

[image: screenshot1]

If I press *View full log*, I can see *Installation complete!* at the top and the last log is *All upgrades installed*, however it is confusing as the progress bar is showing 12/13.

[image: screenshot2]

I tried to use the traditional ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso installer. There is no issue and I can go through all steps. Is there any issue on the new Ubuntu installer with ESXi 6.5 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, this means that your installation is already finished. the last step you see in the bottom bar (12/13) is the pending reboot that you need to perform in order to finalize the installation.

You can see more about installation on the official installation document [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it is already finished at this state (12 of 13) after observing HDD writes for the virtual machine I was installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Server on.

HDD writes kept being 0 B for a while, so it is safe to reboot and finish the installation by doing so. You'll be prompted to remove the installation media and strike "Enter" after that.